# 2004 Kawasaki Ninja EX250. Power Issues

Tags: motorcycle, battery, kawasaki, ninja

I was riding and my bike turned off at random and no car jump will jump it. I turn the key and there is no power at all. I have a fuse checker from my truck and I get no light on any of my fuses. When I plug my batter into my charger it says full. I get absolutely no electric power.  All my wires look fine. I get nothing when I turn the key. Please, anyone help. I have not ridden my bike in a while so I think it’s the battery but I want here what you guys think[image]

Comment: First bike so I’m not very knowledgeable on bikes. Someone please help

Comment: Do the warning lights come on when you turn the key? The headlights? If not check the main battery lead connections for tightness, follow them and check what they are connected to as well. A multimeter will be very useful...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you said you checked the battery and it was good, why are you doubting the battery? It would seem to me the connection to the battery, either on the ground or the positive, is probably at fault. Check all the connections, on either side, using a multi-meter to verify voltages. You'll probably find where the disconnect is at going that way.

Comment: Well I don’t know how long the battery has been on that bike. That’s one thing I did not change. The charger thing that came with the bike that plugs up it says full and the faulty light is not on. I get nothing when I turn the key I men’s like there is nothing no powere running anywhere.

Comment: Have you put a multi-meter against the battery to see what it shows? Even a so called "dead" battery will have power, just not enough to start the engine (unless the battery has a dead short). It sounds like the battery isn't making the power connection for the bike.

Answer (score 3):

Followed the cable to my ignition switch and turns out it had unplugged.

Comment: Glad you found the issue :o) Don't hesitate to select your own answer as "the answer"!

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to check:

1) The connection at the battery. The cable could be lose or corroded. Mind you, it would have to be really badly corroded to have no power at all.

2) The main fuse. Sometimes there is a main fuse between the fuse panel and the battery. It may be attached to a relay. If the fuse was missing or blown, it woul stop the flow.

If both those are fine, it may be the ground. Try using a multimeter to track where power exists and where it doesn’t. Attach the ground lead straight to the battery and see if you have power at the fuse box.

Comment: Okay I’m getting my battery tested currently. I will check those if it come back good and my bike stays indoors so no corrosion on the terminals I did check that

Comment: So I checked the battery and it’s good.... the fuse main fuse I had was blown I replaced that one. There is a black block fuse idk what that is. I it’s near the main fuse

Comment: All my grounds look good no rust nothing

Comment: Battery is fine... no power still got a multi meter and don’t know what to do or how to us eit but I spoke to a repair guy and he said it could be the ignition?

Comment: I fixed it my ignition switch cable came unplugged

Comment: @SantiJoaquin Awesome! Good job on the fix. Now you should add your own answer and mark it so the the rest of the community knows what happened and what to check.

Comment: added thanks guys for your help as well. without you guys telling em to check my cables i probably would have not found it